# scrapy - How to retrieve a variable value using regex

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I want to retrieve the value of the `var modelCode`. I made a regex function like this, but it doesn't work at all. I've posted the structure of the page below.Can somebody help me, please?

```
regex2 = re.compile(r'"var modelCode"\s*:\s*(.+?\})', re.DOTALL)
source_json3 = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'if(pageTrackName == 'product detail' || pageTrackName == 'generic product details')')]/text()").re_first(regex2)
source_json3 = re.sub(r'//[^\n]+', "", source_json3)
```

Structure of the page:

```
var pageTrackName = digitalData.page.pageInfo.pageTrack;
if(pageTrackName == "product detail" || pageTrackName == "generic product details"){ 
   var modelCode = "GT-P5100TSABTU";
   var displayName = "Galaxy Tab 2 (10.1, 3G)".replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
   digitalData.product.model_code = modelCode;
   digitalData.product.displayName = displayName;
   pageName += ":" + modelCode;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is inside a `<script>` tag, I suppose. In that case, you could use:

```
model_code = response.xpath('//script').re_first('modelCode.*?"(.*)"')
```

Some tips:

- You don't have to compile the regex to use `.re_first()`/`.re()`.
- If you use parentheses it will return just the match group inside them.
- More info about `parsel` (`scrapy`'s libraty to extract data from xml): https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll make a lecture based on your recommandation! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?<=var modelCode = ")(.+)(?=";)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CPaZtA/1)

we need not do the re.sub as we get the value of modelCode as the match.